# How to concat or delete letters of the current value in input field (redux edit todo item)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Currently I am trying to add an edit function to my todo app and the problem I have now is that it gets the current value, but it is not possible to delete or add letters. Check the first input field in the snippet where I am talking about in this case.

In order to the entire picture I will include the link to this codesandbox. (components/TodoList.js)

[Link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/chiholiu/todo-redux-filter)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { 
    toggleTodo, 
    editTodo,
    updateEdit,
    getEditText
} from '../actions/index';

const TodoList = ({ 
    todoArray, 
    toggleTodo, 
    editTodo,
    updateEdit,
    getEditText
}) => {
    console.log(todoArray);
    let todos = todoArray.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            item.edit ?
            <div key={i}>
            
            
            
            // I am talking about this input field.....
            <input value={item.todoText} onChange={(e) => getEditText(e.target.value, item.id)}/>
            <button onClick={() => updateEdit(item.id)}>Save</button>
            Edit
            </div>
            :
            <div key={i}>
                <div className="todo-text">
                    {item.todoText}
                </div>
              
                <input type="checkbox" checked={item.complete} onChange={() => toggleTodo(item.id)} />
                <button onClick={() => editTodo(item.id)}>Edit</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
  
    return (
        <div>
           {todos}
        </div>
    )
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    toggleTodo: id => dispatch(toggleTodo(id)),
    editTodo: id => dispatch(editTodo(id)),
    updateEdit: id => dispatch(updateEdit(id)),
    getEditText: text => dispatch(getEditText(text))
});

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    todoArray: state.todo
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoList);
```

Comment: take a look at object shorthand form of mapDispatchToProps to avoid mistakes like this https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect#object-shorthand-form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `mapDispatchToProps()`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleTodo: id => dispatch(toggleTodo(id)),
  editTodo: id => dispatch(editTodo(id)),
  updateEdit: id => dispatch(updateEdit(id)),
  getEditText: (editText, todoId) => dispatch(getEditText(editText, todoId)) // edited
});
```

Additional information: For local states, specifically for form states, it's okay to have a local state. Consider using **Formik** https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview for form state management.

Answer (score 2):

Tiny mistake,`getEditText` should receive two parameters

```
 getEditText: (text) => dispatch(getEditText(text))
```

Your action

```
export const getEditText = (editText, todoId ) => ({
    type: types.GET_EDIT_TEXT,
    editText,
    id: todoId
})
```

change like below

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    toggleTodo: id => dispatch(toggleTodo(id)),
    editTodo: id => dispatch(editTodo(id)),
    updateEdit: id => dispatch(updateEdit(id)),
    getEditText: (text,id) => dispatch(getEditText(text,id))//here
});
```

Comment: Yes your answer is also right, but I assign the green marked to the one who gave the first answer :)

Comment: Don't worry!but just look at my answer time!